# Detect setOnScrollListener in Listview properly after setting Listview height dynamically

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I am using listview inside Viewpager where I need to set ListView height based on child and I need to add new Items when user scroll to last position of Listview. But the problem is when I am setting listview height dynamically its making current listview item visible(or selected). That's why getting (calling method to get data) automatically.
Code is given below:

```
int index = lvNetwork.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = lvNetwork.getChildAt(0);
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

    adapter = new NetworkAdapter(activity, R.layout.network_custom_row, networkDataArrayList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvNetwork.setAdapter(adapter);
    Utils.setlistViewHeight(lvNetwork, activity);

    lvNetwork.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);

    lvNetwork.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            int finalItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            Log.d("dataCalling", "visible " + finalItem);
            Log.d("dataCalling", "total " + totalItemCount);

            if (finalItem == totalItemCount) {

                if (preLast != finalItem) {
                    preLast = finalItem;
                    Log.d("dataCalling", String.valueOf(totalItemCount));
                    Log.d("dataCalling", "Page " + nextid);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                      getNetworkFeed();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

setlistviewHeight method inside Utils,

```
public static void setlistViewHeight(ListView listView, Context context) {

    ListAdapter myListAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {

        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, listView);
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup)
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int listViewWidth = screenWidth - 65;
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listViewWidth,
                View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        listItem.measure(widthSpec, 0);

        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount()));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

***This code works good if I do not need to set listview height dynamically.
What should I change here to make it work or any alternative solution to get desire result?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code inside     Utils.setlistViewHeight(lvNetwork, activity); ?

Comment: posted, please check.

Comment: Logs are corrects? visibleItemCount has a correct value?

Comment: Why do you want to set ListView's height dynamically?

Comment: Because I need to use it inside scrollview with few other layout elements.

Comment: Its calling onScroll method multiple times automatically and visibleItemCount increased to total of current item

Comment: How the User is going to scroll with ListView inside ScrollView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is when I am setting listview height dynamically its making current listview item visible

Setting height dynamically is not the problem. Rather, the problem is you are setting the height of the listview as the maximum possible height of listview by calculating height of each item in the list. So what will happen is all the items of the listview will be populated at once and will remain inflated in the list.(NOTE : No view recycling will happen now)

> That's why getting (calling method to get data) automatically

The call is happening because you are setting the height of the listview based on the total number of items in the list. What happens because of this is, all the elements in your listview will be in visible state at any given point of time. Which means your condition

```
if (finalItem == totalItemCount){}
```

will always be true because your visibleItemCount will always be totalItemCount which makes your final item always equal to totalItemCount. (you can verify this by debugging your app).

> What should I change here to make it work or any alternative solution to get desire result?

The best solution I can think of is setting the height of listview if and only if the total height calcuated by you on the basis of heights of all the items is lesser than the height of the screen. Otherwise, set the height of the listview as `MATCH_PARENT`.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int height = size.y;
        if(totalHeight > height){
            params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        }else {
            Log.d("", "");
            params.height = totalHeight
                    + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount()));
        }
```

So this code will prevent making all the views of the listview to become visible and hence onScroll `visibleItemCount` you will receive, will the no of items currently visible.

Comment: The use of ListView when all item populated at any point in time is pointless.

Comment: worked but in other place listview showing only one row. Can you please help me bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Ankit already explained you what's the problem with your code, let me share an alternate solution with you.

As its no good to use listview when you are already populating its items instead it's better to use scrollview and add items dynamically. Scrollview does not have a scroll listener so we customise it to make one.

MyScrollView.Java

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

public interface OnScrollListener {
    void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
}

private OnScrollListener onScrollListener;

public OnScrollListener getOnScrollListener() {
    return onScrollListener;
}

public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener onScrollListener) {
    this.onScrollListener = onScrollListener;
}

public MyScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

    if (onScrollListener != null) {
        onScrollListener.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
}
}
```

We use the scrolllistener in activity like this -

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewScrollActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MyScrollView scrollView;
private LinearLayout container;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
int maxItem = 20;
private View lastItemView;
boolean alreadyExecutingRequest = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_scroll);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    scrollView = (MyScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    scrollView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    addItemsAsynchronously();
}

private MyScrollView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new    MyScrollView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

        if (lastItemView != null && !alreadyExecutingRequest) {
            Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
            scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
            if (lastItemView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                // Any portion of the lastitem view, even a single pixel, is within the visible window
                addItemsAsynchronously();
            }
        }
    }
};

private void addItemsAsynchronously() {

    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            alreadyExecutingRequest = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addItemsToContainer();
            alreadyExecutingRequest = false;
        }


    }.execute();
}

private void addItemsToContainer() {
    int lastAddedItem = container.getChildCount();
    for (int i=lastAddedItem;i<maxItem;i++) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.new_item, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Item - " + i);

        container.addView(view);
    }
    lastItemView = container.getChildAt(container.getChildCount() -1);
    maxItem+=10;
}
}
```

Here what we did is we checked the last item bound with the scrollview bounds, so it the view is visible then we are at the bottom, so add further items.

activity_new_scroll.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sj.textinputlayout.MyScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sj.textinputlayout.NewScrollActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</com.sj.textinputlayout.MyScrollView>
```

new_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```